# Why does IATA's Timatic ask for the countries visited over the past 6 days when searching for a destination?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, online-resources, timatic

Why does IATA's Timatic (https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/) ask for the countries visited over the past 6 days when searching for a destination?

I understand that immigration officers sometimes need to look at the recent travel history when deciding whether to grant entry, but I wonder why choosing 6 days and not some other amount of days.

[image]

Comment: There are rules about ”returning from” a country (e.g. when transiting in the Schengen area after a visit to the US), 6-day might be a (somewhat arbitrary) threshold to capture that.

Answer (score 6):

Some countries—notably India and Singapore—[require arriving travelers](https://www.who.int/ith/ITH_country_list.pdf) to present a Yellow Fever [Vaccination Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carte_Jaune) if they have been in a country where yellow fever transmission is endemic within the past six days. Other countries with this requirement are a bit vaguer about the exact timing, but six days seems a reasonable rule of thumb even in such cases.